# Application-defined error when looping through ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to loop through different ranges replacing the cells with the value '1' with another value/format.

If I use the ranges one by one, it works great. But when I'm trying to combine the different ranges and loop through the array I'm getting an Application-defined Runtime error at the .Pattern part.

I've read it has something to do with not defining the sheet, but I'm not sure how to do that correctly in this set-up.

I already tried:

- the code with a single range without the i-loop: code works
- add ActiveSheet to the with-loop: With Activesheet.Range(DRng).cell: fail
- add different ways to refer to the range/sheet: fail
- cell.select before with cell.interior

  ```
  Sub SetTelSlot()


  Dim cell As Range
  Dim DRng(1 To 5) As Range
  Dim i As Long


  Set DRng(1) = Range("E7:AB33")
  Set DRng(2) = Range("E45:AB71")
  Set DRng(3) = Range("E82:AB108")
  Set DRng(4) = Range("E119:AB145")
  Set DRng(5) = Range("E156:AB182")


  For i = LBound(DRng) To UBound(DRng)

  For Each cell In DRng(i)
      If cell.Value = "1" Then


  With cell.Interior
          .Pattern = xlSolid        '==>this is giving the error
          .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .Color = RGB(0, 204, 153)
          .TintAndShade = 0
          .PatternTintAndShade = 0
      End With
      cell.Font.Bold = SetBold
      cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
      cell.Value = "T"

      End If

      Next cell

  Next i

  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File autosaves and protects when I close it.
Forgot to unprotect the sheet. 
Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion: instead of looping through every cell in every range you could just build a single range object which comprises all ranges, and search for matching cells in this range:

```
Sub SetTelSlot()
    Dim c As Range, DRng As Range
    Dim firstfound As String

    With ActiveSheet
        Set DRng = Union( _
            .Range("E7:AB33"), _
            .Range("E45:AB71"), _
            .Range("E82:AB108"), _
            .Range("E119:AB145"), _
            .Range("E156:AB182") _
        )
    End With
    With DRng
        Set c = .Find("1", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstfound = c.Address
            Do
                ' action
                With c
                    .Font.Bold = SetBold
                    .Font.Color = vbBlack
                    .Value = "T"
                    With .Interior
                        .pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = RGB(0, 204, 153)
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End With

                ' find next
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop While c.Address <> firstfound
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The `FindNext` method will wrap around to the beginning of the range after reaching it's end; so the first matching address is compared to end the loop.